# Read config from property file and replace it with matching key with value in beans.xml not working

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I am new to Spring environment, trying to read configs from `application.properties` file reside under resources directory and replace the matching key name with value in `beans.xml` file. But it didn't work, here are the config details

**application.properties**

```
queue.name=Tasks
broker.value=tcp://192.168.1.3:61616
```

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd"
>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${broker.value}" />
    </bean>
    ......
</beans>
```

**Exception**

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in
>   class path resource [beans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'broker.value' in value "${broker.value}"; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'broker.value' in value "${broker.value}"

**Edit**

Loading bean.xml file from Application file

```
 @Bean
    public CamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"beans.xml"});
        return new SpringCamelContext(context);
    }
```

Comment: How are you loading the `beans.xml` file?

Comment: if you are using apring-boot, you should not use beans.xml, thats the good of Spring boot, less config files, and all your confing in your Java code. Have a look here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated the post.

Comment: Then you are problably not loading the `application.properties` you think you are loading.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the hint, while running `mvn package` command instead of supplying needed config details in `test/application.properties` I did it on`main/application.properties` files. This was the source for the error. After added relevant config in test property file, it works.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have one more issue, during production run I am supplying external property file for packaging the app using `-Dspring.config.location=/path/to/property` on that time the key-value mapping in beans.xml doesn't pick the value. My guess is, I have defined placeholder to check for application.property file in classpath on beans.xml so it getting value from application.property file in classpath not from external file. If this is an issue, is there any way to overcome this problem.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot then why do you have an xml to read? The property placeholder you are using doesn't know anything about the rest of the world only what you tell it to.